# What is the difference between a JOIN and a RELATIONSHIP in hook_views_data_alter()

Tags: 7, views, hooks

What is the difference between these two as implemented on `hook_views_data_alter()`? Why choose one over the other?

I did notice that in setting up a `relationship` between `mytable1` and `users` tables, the Views UI gave me the option to add the `mytable1.uid` field under the relationship section, that way allows me to add `users` fields into the query.

What am I supposed to notice on the views-UI when I implement a `join` on a table? My implementation is as follows:

```
mymodule_views_data_alter(&$data){

    $data['mytable1']['table']['join']['users'] = array(
        'left_field' => 'uid',
        'field' => 'uid',
    );

}
```

I did this without a relationship setting, so I can observe the exclusive effect of each(`join` vs `relationship`)

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, a join is always done when the query is executed. This means that you can utilise the fields on the joined tables without adding a relationship in the view. When a join is used, I don't think the views information tied to that table is pulled in. For example, you won't be able to add relationships tied to that table.

A relationship is a choice that the user can make on the view. They can choose to add the relationship (from the section on the right side of the view). When a relationship is added, the views information tied to that entity is also pulled in. For example, you will be able to add relationships linked to that table.